Tableau - how to make one filter influence another one from other source
There is a Tableau dashboard with one source - a SQL query containing personal data for each account_id, with each user belonging to a specific city. Additionally, there are several other sources - other SQL queries that do not include account_id but contain data grouped by cities.
I am going to create a dashboard where personal data from the SQL query will be displayed at the top, and information about the city of the selected account will be displayed at the bottom.
How can I set up such filtering so that when a specific account is selected, the data for its city is displayed at the bottom?
i don't know how to synchronize data by account_id city
